# Missing number error for using Spy in LuaLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, pstricks

I have a diagram involving lens and beams made using `pst-optexp` package for convenience and accuracy. So I had to use LuaLaTeX for compilation. However I would like to use the `spy` library from `tikz` for magnification purpose in some part of the diagram. The problem is whenever I use the `\spy` command, I get the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
{
l.25    \end{tikzpicture}
```

The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\newsavebox\Lens

\begin{document}
    \savebox\Lens={
    \begin{pspicture}
        \pnodes(0,0){A}(3,0){B}
        \pnodes(6.5,0){E}(0.5,0){F}
        \lens[n=1.5,lensheight=2.54,lenswidth=0.9,lensradiusleft=2.264,lensradiusright=0](A)(B){}
        \drawbeam[linecolor=black,beamangle=0,beampos=0,linewidth=0.6\pslinewidth](F){1}(E)
        \drawbeam[linecolor=blue,beamangle=0,beampos=0.75,linewidth=0.6\pslinewidth](F){1}(E)
        \drawbeam[linecolor=purple,beamangle=0,beampos=1,linewidth=0.6\pslinewidth](F){1}(E)
        \drawbeam[linecolor=green,beamangle=0,beampos=-0.75,linewidth=0.6\pslinewidth](F){1}(E)
        \drawbeam[linecolor=yellow,beamangle=0,beampos=-1,linewidth=0.6\pslinewidth](F){1}(E)
        \psline(6.5,-0.25)(6.5,0.25)
    \end{pspicture}
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=4,size=2cm}]
    \node at (0,0){\usebox\Lens};
%%  \spy on (1,0) in node at (3,-2); <-- Issue with this line
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: Output without spy command]

My desired output should be something like this:
[image]

I do not know about the `spy` equivalent in PSTricks. What could be the cause of such an error?

Comment: `\savebox\Lens=` typesets = and saves it in the box  I guess you intended `\sbox\Lens{\begin{tikzpicture....`

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
  %     pgf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
  \directlua{
  local lft = lua.get_functions_table()
  lft[\string#lft+1] = function()
      local lhs = token.scan_string()
      local rhs = token.scan_string()
      if lhs < rhs then
          tex.sprint(-2, "-1")
      elseif lhs == rhs then
          tex.sprint(-2, "0")
      else
          tex.sprint(-2, "1")
      end
  end
  token.set_lua("pgfsys@strcmp", \string#lft, "global")
  }


\typeout{^^J!!!!1: \meaning\pgfsys@strcmp^^J\pgfsys@strcmp{aa}{bb}}

%\directlua{require'luapstricks'}%
\directlua{
local func = luatexbase.new_luafunction'luaPST'
token.set_lua('luaPST', func, 'protected')
lua.get_functions_table()[func] = function()
 local x = token.scan_string()
end
}

\typeout{^^J!!!!2:  \meaning\pgfsys@strcmp^^J\pgfsys@strcmp{aa}{bb}}


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

both `!!!` tests should be -1 as `aa` is not `bb` but the second returns `{bb}` which ultimately gives the error in the title.

the actual definition of `\pgfsys@strcmp` is the same in both cases (`luacall #25`) which means somewhere the lua table of declared tex functions is messed up....

---

So putting it together

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\makeatletter
\e@alloc@luafunction@count=\directlua{tex.print(table.getn(lua.get_functions_table()))}\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\newsavebox\Lens

\begin{document}
    \savebox\Lens{%%%%<<<<
    \begin{pspicture}
        \pnodes(0,0){A}(3,0){B}
        \pnodes(6.5,0){E}(0.5,0){F}
        \lens[n=1.5,lensheight=2.54,lenswidth=0.9,lensradiusleft=2.264,lensradiusright=0](A)(B){}
        \drawbeam[linecolor=black,beamangle=0,beampos=0,linewidth=0.6\pslinewidth](F){1}(E)
        \drawbeam[linecolor=blue,beamangle=0,beampos=0.75,linewidth=0.6\pslinewidth](F){1}(E)
        \drawbeam[linecolor=purple,beamangle=0,beampos=1,linewidth=0.6\pslinewidth](F){1}(E)
        \drawbeam[linecolor=green,beamangle=0,beampos=-0.75,linewidth=0.6\pslinewidth](F){1}(E)
        \drawbeam[linecolor=yellow,beamangle=0,beampos=-1,linewidth=0.6\pslinewidth](F){1}(E)
        \psline(6.5,-0.25)(6.5,0.25)
    \end{pspicture}%%%%%<<<<<
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle,black,magnification=4,size=2cm}]
    \node at (0,0){\usebox\Lens};
  \spy on (-3.3,-5.8) in node at (3,-2);% <-- Issue with this line
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'll raise an issue at latex2e/base, I think ltluatex should keep
`\e@alloc@luafunction@count` and the size of the lua function table in sync.

Comment: The code did what I wanted. But from your discussion in the answer, was it a bug?

Comment: @SolidMark well at the github link I suggested it's a bug in latex, an alternative view would be that it's a bug in pgf, not allocating via the latex allocator as used by luapstricks. Either  way we'll sort it out and get things fixed